# Varnish: How to use `std.ip()` to set a header value

Tags: http-headers, varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I am trying to use [**`std.ip`**](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/reference/vmod_std.generated.html#func-ip) which is a part of varnish 4.0 to to return the client IP which should be the first valid IP address in the **X-Forwarded-For** header, if the example in the documentation is correct.

```
varnishtest "Test v4 vcl X-Forwarded-For Header logic"

server s1 {
   rxreq
   expect req.http.X-Real-IP == "2.1.1.1"
   expect req.http.X-Forwarded-For == "2.1.1.1, 3.3.3.3, 3.3.3.3, 127.0.0.1"
   txresp
} -start

varnish v1 -vcl+backend {
   sub vcl_recv {
      set req.http.X-Real-IP = std.ip(req.http.X-Forwarded-For, "0.0.0.0");
   }
} -start

client c1 {
   txreq -url "/" -hdr "X-Forwarded-For: 2.1.1.1, 3.3.3.3, 3.3.3.3"
   rxresp
}

client c1 -run
```

The above dies an ugly death:

```
...
***  v1    0.9 debug| Assert error in vwk_thread(), waiter/cache_waiter_kqueue.c line 115:\n
***  v1    0.9 debug|   Condition(read(vwk->pipe[0], &c, 1) == 1) not true.\n
...
```

And does not behave as I would want by returning the first IP address.

### Updated

Alternatively I have found that the following does work for the same purposes, But still could not get **`std.ip`** to work:

```
varnish v1 -vcl+backend {
   sub vcl_recv {
      set req.http.X-Real-IP = regsub(req.http.X-Forwarded-For, "\s*,.*$", "");
   }
} -start
```

As a follow up question. This `vcl_recv{...}` logic actually lives in my `default.vcl` file, where all my backends, probes are defined. But when I try to test that code by including into a varnishtest file as follows:

```
varnish v1 -vcl+backend {
        include "/path/to/file.vcl";
} -start
```

The test does not get the `expect` statements in the server `s1`. If someone could give some clarity on the following I'd be much ablighed:

1. Why does `std.ip(req.http.X-Forwarded-For, "0.0.0.0")` not behave as expected?
2. How can I test an included `default.vcl` with expect statements in the set server `s1`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the line

**import std;**

at the top of your vcl file